# XMLHttpRequest doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript

I can't understand why my function returns empty date. If I use REST client it returns my correct date.

```
function requestData(data) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url + data, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
            var info = xhr.responseText;
            return info;
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}
```

Is anyone can explain me why I retrieve empty data?

Comment: You can't return from AJAX request. Read detailed description of the problem in the linked question.

Comment: I think this question isn't duplicate. The question marked as duplicate mention jQuery and ajax, here it is raw XMLHTTP manipulations.

Comment: I don't use jQuery. So the questions aren't duplicates.

Comment: You either have to set up an asynchronous callback or perform the request synchronously

Comment: XHR is working properly. The issue is library agnostic, so while the dupe uses jQuery, the issue you're asking about is the same.

Comment: @RobinCarlier: The issue is the same. Doesn't matter what (if any) library is used. All that does is put the above code behind a generic function call.